# Why is it called a 'feminine rhyme'?

Tags: etymology, rhymes

While researching for the rhyme scheme used by hip-hop artists (Hail Eminem!), I found [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminine_rhyme):

> A feminine rhyme is a rhyme that matches two or more syllables, usually at the end of respective lines, in which the final syllable or syllables are unstressed. It is also commonly known as double rhyme.

An example of a rhyme that qualifies as feminine is *fashion* with *passion*.

Now, as Wikipedia articles go, this isn't one of the better ones. There is no clue as to *why* it's named that way.

Consulting [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=feminine%20rhyme&searchmode=none) and [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feminine-rhyme?q=feminine%20rhyme) didn't help.

Does anyone know why is the double rhyme also called the female/feminine rhyme? And please shed some light on the origin of [masculine rhyme](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/masculine-rhyme) as well.

PS - It seems hip-hop artists call these 'multies'. Short for multisyllabic rhymes.

---

**EDIT:** My reasearch has taught me what these terms mean. So please answer regarding the origin only. And it would be good if there is some attribution, because the terms invite speculation.

Comment: Translation from another language? Feminine words in French often have unaccented *e*'s on the end, and thus result in feminine rhymes. (These *e*'s are silent in French today, but are still pronounced when reading poetry.)

Comment: Huh, good question. It always just sort of made intuitive sense to me—the double rhyme kind of feels more elegant and well-ordered and feminine somehow, while the single rhyme feels more brute-forced and pushy—but that's probably just my own internal post-rationalising based on the names.

Comment: Maybe you came across this. Still, have a look at this [Feminine-Masculine](http://vicariousoul.deviantart.com/art/Masculine-vs-Feminine-Rhymes-287053088)

Comment: @Mrstupid That looks like it would be good to put in an answer.

Comment: @Mrstupid: That link still explains just the terms, not their origin. At best, it's speculative, post-rationalizing like Janus did.

Comment: @TusharRaj what about [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=uff2N62Jx9wC&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=feminine+rhythm+Origin&source=bl&ots=ZklDzkeeIM&sig=R0cU3C90Pf7NwYUFaTuJhEAglGQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5S13Vc2bMaWwmwWA94LACQ&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=feminine%20rhythm%20Origin&f=false)?

Comment: And evidence for my theory: From [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime): Une rime est prononcée *féminine* lorsque le dernier phonème est un *e* caduc (nommé autrefois « *e* féminin »). translated: "A rhyme is called *féminine* when the last phoneme is a mute *e* (formerly called an "e féminin"). So in French, a rhyme was feminine if the line ended with a *"feminine e"*.

Comment: @Mrstupid: Another dead end. That link contains what Peter Shor said. And it does have an origin of `rhyme`, but not of 'feminine' or 'masculine rhyme'

Comment: @PeterShor: So the e feminin was the technical term for the mute e? And that's how the rhyme got named?

Comment: @Tushar: I don't have any solid evidence for that, but this is certainly what the French Wikipedia article implies. (Nobody calls it an *e féminin* anymore, as far as I know, and I don't know whether it was a technical term or just a commonly-used term.)

Comment: On the basis of the number of syllables presenting similarity of sound, we have: (1) ***masculine rhyme***, in which the correspondence of sound is restricted to the final accented syllable as in "fan" and "ran." This type of rhyme is generally ***more forcible, more vigorous***  than those following; (2) ***feminine rhyme***, in which the rhyming stressed syllable is followed by an ***undifferentiated unstressed syllable exactly matching another such unstressed syllable*** in the other rhyme words

Comment: TusharRaj It comes from the French analysis of poetry like @PeterShor said, les Alexendrines, hexametre iambique, Moliere, et tout ca.

Comment: @Mitch: That's certainly seems to a strong possibility.

Comment: Why was a "mute *e*" formerly called a "feminine *e*"? (It couldn't have been called a "mute *e*" when it was still pronounced.) Because you stuck a "feminine *e*" on the end of adjectives and some nouns to turn them from male to female. For example: a black cat is *"un chat noir*" or *"une chatte noire"* depending on whether it's a boy or a girl cat.

Comment: @Mrstupid: I truly appreciate your efforts and your tenacity. Thanks.

Comment: @Mitch: since standard Parisian French doesn't have stressed syllables (and hasn't since at least the 15th century), I believe that *hexamètre iambique* in French is something only found in poetry in foreign languages.

Comment: @PeterShor: Your case seems pretty strong now.

Comment: @TusharRaj You're welcome! I hope you find your answer.

Comment: @PeterShor You may be using logic, where I am only using half faded memory of highschool French. A quick wiki.fr search shows that classic French poetry was structured using spondees and dactyls and such ([l'hexamètre dactylique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hexam%C3%A8tre_dactylique&redirect=no)). So the spoken language certainly doesn't have word stress, but their poetry is analyzed using it.

Comment: @Mitch: you're absolutely right ... some of it was (although my memory from vague high school French is that a large portion of French poetry, including Villon and Beaudelaire, can't be analyzed that way).

Comment: English rhyme is based on matching the **rime** of the last stressed syllable. It is masculine rhyme when there are no further syllables, feminine rhyme otherwise. Unstressed syllables in feminine rhyme must match ***identically*** rather than merely sharing rimes as is required in the stressed syllable. **Modern** English rhyme ultimately came to us from Italian; think of Dante’s *terza rima*. It is **tail-rhyme** based on stressed syllabic rime rather than the **head-rhyme** based on the alliteration of initial consonants or consonant clusters of Old English and sometimes of Middle English.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The names come from French, where (from [French Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime))

> A rhyme is called feminine when the last phoneme is a mute *e* (formerly called an "e féminin").

That is, a rhyme was called feminine if the words ended with a *mute e*. Back when the rules for French poetry were formulated, these *e*'s were pronounced, but unstressed, and one name for them was *feminine e*'s. Mute *e*'s are still pronounced when reading poetry and when singing, although not in normal speech.

Why were they called *feminine e*'s? It probably didn't have anything to do with *mute e*'s being weaker or more girly-sounding in any sense; they were called *feminine e*'s because, to turn male adjectives and some male nouns into female ones, you added a *mute e*.  For example, in French, a big black cat is:

> *un gros chat noir* (boy cat),
>   *une grosse chatte noire* (girl cat).

This rule in French applies only for adjectives and some nouns which have male/female versions (e.g., *chanteur, chanteuse*); there are quite a few masculine nouns that end in *mute e*'s and feminine nouns that don't.

You can see that the name *"feminine rhyme*" originated in French by looking at the reference (from London, 1764) T Romano gives in his answer, where a feminine rhyme is defined as one ending in an *e*-mute. In English, words (e.g., *state* and *gait*) rhyme whether or not they end in a silent *e*.

Comment: Why not add your remark that in French poetry [or song] this -e is unstressed rather than mute? This is not an academic distinction - I recently had to sing [Lauridsen's Chansons des Roses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf2b4Jb-Tb8), which ignores this; it feels awkward to me and led to disagreements with other choir members.

Comment: @reinierpost: Done. Listening to *Chansons des Roses*, it seems that Lauridsen pronounces some of the mute *e*'s and not others, which I think might be more disconcerting than if he used either alternative consistently.

Comment: could anyone give ONE EXAMPLE of a feminine rhyme in English??

Comment: @Joe: *sample* and *trample*. Examples are quite easily [Googleable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminine_rhyme).

Comment: @PeterShor: Not sure that's the best example - those words don't actually rhyme in, for example, standard British English. Perhaps *pleasure* and *treasure*? (Must resist temptation to suggest *pleasure*/*leisure*, which rhymes in BrE but not always in AmE...)

Comment: Plenty of masculine words in French end in mute *e*, such as *programme* and *problème*. Most of these are ultimately of Greek origin.

Comment: @tchrist: I never said that there weren't any. Maybe I should be more explicit about this in my answer.

Comment: @JoeBlow This is replete with feminine rhyme, occurring not only at line-ends but alternating with occurrences at the half-line: *There was a merry passenger, /
A messenger a mariner: /
He built a gilded gondola /
To wander in and had in her /
A load of yellow oranges /
And porridge for his provender; /
He perfumed her with marjoram, / 
And cardamom and lavender.* There is much, much more where that came from.

Comment: Hi tchrist - yes it's a double rhyme.  (I had no idea "feminine rhyme" was a synonym for same.)

Comment: Just another note about French, there are also quite a few masculine *adjectives* in French that end in *e* (normally they are invariant for gender), like *rouge, pauvre, difficile, stupide, possible*.

Answer (score 10):

According to volume 4 of [*A New and Complete Dictionary of Arts and Sciences: Comprehending All the Branches of Useful Knowledge, with Accurate Descriptions as Well of the Various Machines, Instruments, Tools, Figures, and Schemes Necessary for Illustrating Them, as of the Classes, Kinds, Preparations, and Uses of Natural Productions, Whether Animals, Vegetables, Minerals, Fossils, Or Fluids; Together with the Kingdoms, Provinces, Cities, Towns, and Other Remarkable Places Throughout the World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5Yw9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA2786&dq=%22feminine+rhyme%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BjR3VYPeHozjsASf_IHQBw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22feminine%20rhyme%22&f=false) (London, 1764),

> a feminine rhyme is that where the last syllable of the rhyme ends
>   with an *e*-mute

The passage goes on to say:

> There is no rule in poetry...whose observance costs so much trouble,
>   and is productive of less beauties in verse, than that of rhyming...

Comment: Great find! Of course, this is only true in French. But rhymes with a "mute *e*" on the end of a line in French poetry produces a similar effect to two-syllable rhymes, with the second syllable unstressed, in English, German and Russian poetry.

Comment: In French for sure, but not only in French.  (https://books.google.com/books?id=uKiC6IeFR2UC&pg=PA848&lpg=PA848&dq=feminine+rhyme+in+chaucer&source=bl&ots=avQ3Chkgvm&sig=kxDxB2Db_j2J-lcewpHExJW3pX4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XEJ3Ve6kGsPLsASSzrmABA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=feminine%20rhyme%20in%20chaucer&f=false)

Comment: Otherwise known as "A New and Complete Dictionary of Arts and Sciences: Being the First Book Whose Subtitle was a Chapter in its Own Right."

Comment: this "a feminine rhyme is that where the last syllable of the rhyme ends with an e-mute" would seem to have nothing to do with a "double rhyme" - I'm confused by it!

Comment: @Joe Blow: There's a paragraph devoted to the confusing nomenclature in the entry from the *Princeton Encyclopedia of Poetry and Poetics*; see the link in my comment directly above.

Comment: Huh fascinating Tim, thanks for that clarification

Answer (score 1):

According To the following [source](http://billkirkwrites.blogspot.it/2012/01/masculinefeminine-rhyme-who-knew.html) it comes  from the French language distinction of words according to gender and the *'weak'* rhymes that unaccented syllables suggest.

> - According to one source in the English Department at Carson-Newman College, (http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/lit_terms_R.html) the word "rhyme" itself originates "from Old French, rime meaning 'series,' in turn adopted from Latin 'rithmus' and Greek 'rhythmos'." ***Given some of the other gender assignments in Greek and Latin, might we ascribe gender features to the rhyming verses penned by the early Greeks and Romans?***
> - No doubt, the definition of gender in rhyme could probably be argued until the cows come home, with a break taken only for milking before the debate starts again. As is true with virtually any sorting out of why words in any language might be classified as masculine versus feminine, rhymes are no different. ***One thing seems clear: at least in English, gender in rhyme seems to have little or nothing to do with the gender rules found in some romance languages.**
> - That is, whether a line of verse in English ends in an "a" or "o" or other gender laden vowel or consonant, doesn't really matter as much as it does in the Spanish language. And speaking of word endings, despite its compromise value in the Italian language, the use of a neutral vowel (such as the letter "i") at the end of the plural form of both masculine and feminine words is not a gender-driven issue in English rhyme. But you have to admire the logical recognition of not being able to sort out gender in groups.
> - ***In the French language, the definition suggests line ending words which end in "e" are feminine and those that don't are masculine. Some sources also refer to "e" endings and unaccented ending syllables as being weak***.

(billkirkwrites.blogspot)

Comment: In French, *adjectives* that end in "e" are feminine, and *adjectives* that don't are masculine. For nouns, this only works with nouns that come in gendered pairs (e.g., *chanteur* and *chanteuse* or *chien* and *chienne*).